Application of Differentiation: Optimisation Problem
I have a question regarding using calculus to solve an optimisation problem. It is as follows:
A utility company has a small power plant that can produce x kilowatt hours of electricity daily at a cost of $ 10 - \frac{x}{10^5}$ cents each for $ 0 \le x \le 8 \times 10^5$. Consumers will use $10^5\times(10 -  \frac{p}{2})$ kilowatt hours of electricity daily at a price of p cents per kilowatt hour. What price should the utility charge to maximise its profit?
I know the profit is revenue - cost, and the revenue is p $\times 10^5 \times (10 - \frac{p}{2})$. I also know that the total cost for producing x kilowatt hours is x $\times  (10 - \frac{x}{10^5})$.
However, I don't understand why x = $ 10^5 \times (10 - \frac{p}{2})$ is used in the final profit equation.
Thanks!

The question states that the consumer will use $10^5 \times (10-\frac{p}2)$ kilowatts hours of electricity, this quantity can't exceed the supply of electricity or they can't possibly use the electricity that is not provided.  Hence, clearly, we have $$10^5 \times (10-\frac{p}2) \le x.$$
Suppose we produce more electricity than what is required, then the cost increases while the revenue remain the same. Hence the profit won't be maximized.
Hence, we must have $$10^5 \times (10-\frac{p}2) = x.$$

Thank you, Siong Thye Goh!
